# Error while reading: failure in psftp

Tags: sftp, putty

I am trying to get a file from a remote server using PSFTP. But after executing the command "get filename" I get an error "error while reading: failure". I am able to put files easily on the other hand.
Can someone sort this out please??

Answer (score 0):

To get a file in psftp :

```
mget filename.txt
```

To transfer a file in psftp :

```
mput filename.txt
```